# Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

How can I convert the `str` representation of a dictionary, such as the following string, into a `dict`?

```py
s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
```

I prefer not to use `eval`. What else can I use?

Comment: If you can't use Python 2.6, you can use a simple safeeval implmenentation like http://code.activestate.com/recipes/364469/ It piggybacks on the Python compiler so you don't have to do all the gross work yourself.

Comment: **Note**: For those that come here with *deceptively similar looking* **JSON** data, you want to go read [Parse JSON in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/7771011) instead. JSON is *not the same thing as Python*. If you have `"` double quotes around your strings you probably have JSON data. You can also look for `null`, `true` or `false`, Python syntax uses `None`, `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1687, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}")
{'muffin': 'lolz', 'foo': 'kitty'}
```

This is safer than using `eval`.  As its own docs say:

```
>>> help(ast.literal_eval)
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```

For example:

```
>>> eval("shutil.rmtree('mongo')")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 208, in rmtree
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 206, in rmtree
    names = os.listdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mongo'
>>> ast.literal_eval("shutil.rmtree('mongo')")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: I should add that you need to sanitize the string for use with ast.literal_eval. (ensure quotes/double quotes in string are escaped)

Comment: i get this error I am on python 2.6 (x86) on windows 7 x64
  File "D:\Python26\lib\ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval  
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')    
  File "D:\Python26\lib\ast.py", line 36, in parse         
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)    
  File "<unknown>", line 1                                 
                                                           
    ^                                                      
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what about `"dict(a=1)"` style strings?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for enum value inside a dictionary. Eg: d = "{'col': <Colors.RED: 2>, 'val': 2}"

Comment: why don't use json.dumps and json.loads insead, I found this solution more elevant thant using eval

Comment: @n611x007 that's a statement, so it won't be allowed

Comment: I still don't see why it's better than eval(). Is it because it only accepts the structures given?

Comment: I have a naive question. Worried that I may have misunderstood "import". Responder says ast is built-in. Why do I need to import it?

Comment: @JuanB json.loads doesn't accept [single-quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257217/8857601). It also doesn't accept None, only null.

Comment: That nice. My string dict actually included dict inside and <json.loads> method not working.

Answer (score 412):

https://docs.python.org/library/json.html

JSON can solve this problem, though its decoder wants double quotes around keys and values.  If you don't mind a replace hack...

```
import json
s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
json_acceptable_string = s.replace("'", "\"")
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
# d = {u'muffin': u'lolz', u'foo': u'kitty'}
```

NOTE that if you have single quotes as a part of your keys or values this will fail due to improper character replacement. This solution is only recommended if you have a strong aversion to the eval solution.

More about json single quote: [jQuery.parseJSON throws “Invalid JSON” error due to escaped single quote in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

Comment: Another problem is for `"{0: 'Hello'}"`.

Comment: This also fails if you have trailing commas (not JSON compliant), eg: "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty',}"

Comment: Single-quoted strings, tuple literals, and trailing commas are not valid JSON.  `json.loads` will only work on a valid JSON string.  See the spec here: https://www.json.org/

Using `json.loads` is the safest solution, so use if possible.  I would recommend transforming your input into valid JSON if necessary.

Comment: Also this solution does not work if you have unicode strings

Comment: I had a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561257/how-to-convert-string-without-quotes-and-with-arrays-and-sub-dictionary-to-a-dic but without quotes

Comment: Not working if value `None` (without single quotes, so can' t replace), e.g. `"{'d': None}"`

Comment: If your dict structure includes inside another dict etc ..... <json.load> not working. <ast.literal_eval >much usuful for general needs.

Comment: Save my life for **handling a dict posted by a Django form**. In this case, the form is posted as a string . Thanks

Comment: After running into performance issues with `ast.literal_eval`, I am using this now. My source and inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480073/fastest-implementation-of-ast-literal-eval

Answer (score 237):

using `json.loads`:

```
>>> import json
>>> h = '{"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}'
>>> d = json.loads(h)
>>> d
{u'foo': u'bar', u'foo2': u'bar2'}
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: I dont think it answers the OP's answer. How do we use json.laads to convert a string s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}" to dict?

Comment: why is this printing 'u' in the output??
eg - 
str = '{"1":"P", "2":"N", "3":"M"}'
d = json.loads(str)
print d
output is : {u'1': u'P', u'3': u'M', u'2': u'N'}

Comment: @technazi: json.loads(h.replace("'",'"'))

Comment: However, there are limits, e.g.: h= '{"muffin" : "lolz", "foo" : "kitty",}', also  h= '{"muffin's" : "lolz", "foo" : "kitty"}', (just noticed part of the same comments in a similar answer... still leaving here for completeness...)

Comment: In my opinion, that's the shortest and easiest way... Definitely the one I personally prefer.

Comment: @nostradamus Too many exceptions, floating point values, tuples, etc. etc.

Comment: Thx, this seems to be the most concise way. Definitely using it from now on. But gotta keep track of trailing commas and shielded quotations

Comment: This is the best way if the user knows that the `string` is a `json`. The clue to this is the fact that the format has double quotes. `{"key" : "value"}`

Answer (score 55):

To OP's example:

```
s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
```

We can use [Yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) to deal with this kind of non-standard json in string:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
>>> s
"{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
>>> yaml.load(s)
{'muffin': 'lolz', 'foo': 'kitty'}
```

Comment: This will cause 'yes' and 'no' strings to be converted to True / False

Comment: i got my value that works fine....but i get a error with it "AMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details." what is it??

Comment: Only use this yaml parser for *trusted* input. Preferably use `safe_load` to avoid security implications.

Comment: config = yaml.load(ymlfile, Loader=yaml.Loader)

Answer (score 36):

To summarize:

```
import ast, yaml, json, timeit

descs=['short string','long string']
strings=['{"809001":2,"848545":2,"565828":1}','{"2979":1,"30581":1,"7296":1,"127256":1,"18803":2,"41619":1,"41312":1,"16837":1,"7253":1,"70075":1,"3453":1,"4126":1,"23599":1,"11465":3,"19172":1,"4019":1,"4775":1,"64225":1,"3235":2,"15593":1,"7528":1,"176840":1,"40022":1,"152854":1,"9878":1,"16156":1,"6512":1,"4138":1,"11090":1,"12259":1,"4934":1,"65581":1,"9747":2,"18290":1,"107981":1,"459762":1,"23177":1,"23246":1,"3591":1,"3671":1,"5767":1,"3930":1,"89507":2,"19293":1,"92797":1,"32444":2,"70089":1,"46549":1,"30988":1,"4613":1,"14042":1,"26298":1,"222972":1,"2982":1,"3932":1,"11134":1,"3084":1,"6516":1,"486617":1,"14475":2,"2127":1,"51359":1,"2662":1,"4121":1,"53848":2,"552967":1,"204081":1,"5675":2,"32433":1,"92448":1}']
funcs=[json.loads,eval,ast.literal_eval,yaml.load]

for  desc,string in zip(descs,strings):
    print('***',desc,'***')
    print('')
    for  func in funcs:
        print(func.__module__+' '+func.__name__+':')
        %timeit func(string)        
    print('')
```

Results:

```
*** short string ***

json loads:
4.47 µs ± 33.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
builtins eval:
24.1 µs ± 163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
ast literal_eval:
30.4 µs ± 299 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
yaml load:
504 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

*** long string ***

json loads:
29.6 µs ± 230 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
builtins eval:
219 µs ± 3.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
ast literal_eval:
331 µs ± 1.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
yaml load:
9.02 ms ± 92.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Conclusion:
prefer **json.loads**

Comment: Except this won't work with his single-quoted string, which was part of his initial problem.  Performance was never mentioned.

Comment: +1 for the benchmarks (it helps making an informed decision), -1 for the conclusion: as mentioned many times, `json` fails in many cases. Should be up to the user to choose between features vs performance.

Answer (score 25):

If the string can *always* be trusted, you could use `eval` (or use `literal_eval` as suggested; it's safe no matter what the string is.) Otherwise you need a parser. A JSON parser (such as simplejson) would work if he only ever stores content that fits with the JSON scheme.

Comment: Starting in 2.6, simplejson is included in the Python standard library as the json module.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good answer, but note that officially JSON doesn't support single-quoted strings, as given in the original poster's example.

Answer (score 20):

Use `json`. the `ast` library consumes a lot of memory and and slower. I have a process that needs to read a text file of 156Mb. `Ast` with 5 minutes delay for the conversion dictionary `json` and 1 minutes using 60% less memory!

Comment: but has its limits: try converting the string "{'foo':'bar',}"

Answer (score 11):

```
string = "{'server1':'value','server2':'value'}"

#Now removing { and }
s = string.replace("{" ,"")
finalstring = s.replace("}" , "")

#Splitting the string based on , we get key value pairs
list = finalstring.split(",")

dictionary ={}
for i in list:
    #Get Key Value pairs separately to store in dictionary
    keyvalue = i.split(":")

    #Replacing the single quotes in the leading.
    m= keyvalue[0].strip('\'')
    m = m.replace("\"", "")
    dictionary[m] = keyvalue[1].strip('"\'')

print dictionary
```

Comment: Many mistakes in this approach. What if value of a key contains `{` or `}`. What if it is nested `dict`. What if value contains `,` ??

Answer (score 7):

Optimized code of Siva Kameswara Rao Munipalle

```
s = s.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(",")
            
dictionary = {}

for i in s:
    dictionary[i.split(":")[0].strip('\'').replace("\"", "")] = i.split(":")[1].strip('"\'')
            
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 6):

no any libs are used (python2):

```
dict_format_string = "{'1':'one', '2' : 'two'}"
d = {}
elems  = filter(str.isalnum,dict_format_string.split("'"))
values = elems[1::2]
keys   = elems[0::2]
d.update(zip(keys,values))
```

NOTE: As it has hardcoded `split("'")` will work only for strings where data  is "single quoted".

NOTE2: In python3 you need to wrap `filter()` to `list()` to get list.

Comment: elems  = filter(str.isalnum,dict_format_string.split("'")) should be list(elems  = filter(str.isalnum,dict_format_string.split("'"))) without converting to list it would still be 'filter' object

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't use any of the above answers cause I had a string with the dtypes specified, so I used the json.load as follow:

```
string_dict = """{'contexts': array(['Programmed cell death (PCD) is the regulated death of cells within an organism.', ..., '...'], dtype=object)},..."""

# Replace array( with np.array(
string_dict = string_dict.replace("array(", "np.array(")

# Evaluate the string as python code
python_dict = ast.literal_eval(string_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string representation of a Python object that cannot be parsed by `ast.literal_eval` or `json`, then try [asteval](https://newville.github.io/asteval/) module. You can install it via pip first to use it: `pip install asteval`.

Its main advantage over the built-in `ast` or `eval` is that it can evaluate string representations of complex Python objects much easier than `ast` and much more safely than `eval`. Use it especially if your string contains math expressions such as `nan`, `Decimal`, numpy objects etc.

To use it, we must instantiate an `Interpreter` object and call it with the string to evaluate. In the example below, the string representation of the dictionary which is not JSON and contains NaN which cannot be converted by `ast.literal_eval`; however, `asteval.Interpreter` evaluates it correctly.

```py
import ast
import json
from asteval import Interpreter

s = "{1: nan, 2: 3}"
ast.literal_eval(s)     # ValueError: malformed node or string
json.loads(s)           # JSONDecodeError
aeval = Interpreter()
aeval(s)                # {1: nan, 2: 3}
```

Some other examples where `literal_eval` or `json.loads` fails but `asteval` works.

1. If you have the string representation of numpy objects and if numpy is installed on your system, then it's much easier to convert to the proper object with `asteval` as well.

   ```py
   aeval = Interpreter()
   aeval("{'a': array([ 1.,  2., nan])}")    # {'a': array([ 1.,  2., nan])}
   ```
2. By default, `asteval` evaluates numpy functions; however, if you want to make it parse some symbols in a certain way (e.g. numpy dtypes), you can define a custom symbol table and pass it to `Interpreter` at creation.

   Below is an example where a symbol table that defines how to evaluate numpy dtypes, `decimal.Decimal` type and `null` value is created and is passed to the `Interpreter`.

   ```py
   from asteval import Interpreter, make_symbol_table
   from decimal import Decimal

   s = "{'a': array(['text'], dtype=object), 'b': Decimal('3.33'), 'c': null, 'd': array([1, 2], dtype=int8)}"
   symtable = make_symbol_table(object=object, Decimal=Decimal, null=None, int8='int8')
   aeval = Interpreter(symtable=symtable)
   d = aeval(s)
   print(d)   # {'a': array(['text'], dtype=object), 'b': Decimal('3.33'), 'c': None, 'd': array([1, 2], dtype=int8)}
   ```

---

Finally, keep in mind that since it evaluates any numpy/math functions (really any function that is fed into it as long as it is defined in the `symtable` argument), please be mindful of the input you pass into it.

Answer (score 0):

My string didn't have quotes inside:
`s = 'Date: 2022-11-29T10:57:01.024Z, Size: 910.11 KB'`

My solution was to use `str.split`:
`{k:v for k, v in map(lambda d: d.split(': '), s.split(', '))}`

Comment: @EricAya, why did you edit my question out?
How can I do this without a `map`?

Comment: Because the answers section is just for answers, not for questions, this is not a discussion forum. If you have a new question you need to post an actual new question.